# Dart a method calls another method inside to exit

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void methodA() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    checkIfExitMethodA();
    doSomething();
  } else {
    print('nothing');
  }
}

void checkIfExitMethodA() => print('check whether to exit the parent function');
```

Is it possible to implement `checkIfExitMethodA()` method which contains few conditions to check and methods to exucate, and once it meets it will exit `methodA()` entirely?

It can be done by simply putting a `return` but I would like to exit by assessing `checkIfExitMethodA()` before `doSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to do it is to throw exception.

```
void checkIfExitMethodA() => assert(!conditionMet, 'condition met, parent handles...');
```

Comment: You may want to add a way to throw an exception in production code. This would only work in development and then mysteriously fail when used in production.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be a return value to be checked:

```
void methodA() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    if(checkIfExitMethodA()) {
      return;
    }
    doSomething();
  } else {
    print('nothing');
  }
}

bool checkIfExitMethodA() => /* your condition here instead of */ true;
```

There is no "normal" way to tell the caller to exit their method. There is the "exceptional" way mentioned in another answer though, maybe that suits better you:

```
void methodA() {
  if (1 == 1) {
    checkIfExitMethodA();
    doSomething();
  } else {
    print('nothing');
  }
}

void checkIfExitMethodA() {
  if(/* your exit condition*/ true) {
    throw Exception("Condition not met");
  }
}
```

Please note that this will not "exit method A". It will exit *all* methods until you implement a catch block.